# Installing PySimpleGUI on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, installation, python

I've been trying to install PySimpleGUI on Linux Mint. I've tried the following commands in the terminal but whenever I try to import it it says "No module with the name PySimpleGUI exists":

sudo apt-get install python-PySimpleGUI
sudo apt install PySimpleGUI

Pip and tkinter is installed and is upgraded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this command `pip install PySimpleGUI`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT Jan 2021:

As suggested by moderators, I'm including a link

http://www.PySimpleGUI.org

This is where you should go to search for all answers initially.  Start there.  It has the info posted below (this is your backlink the moderators suggested posting).

Another important link is http://Issues.PySimpleGUI.org.  As written in the first link's document, questions should be posted on the project's GitHub, not on forums, stack overflow, Reddit, here, etc.

You'll find if someone else has answered something similar there. The database is much larger than anywhere else on the internet. The package authors are there too along with an active user community that answers questions. The quality of your answers will be higher than elsewhere.

Back to the original answer now that sources are properly cited.

---

It's a Python package on PyPI so it's pip installed. Here is how to install PySimpleGUI on Linux systems:

Installing Python 3

```
pip install --upgrade PySimpleGUI
```

On some systems you need to run `pip3`.

```
pip3 install --upgrade PySimpleGUI
```

On a Raspberry Pi, this is should work:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pysimplegui
```

Some users have found that upgrading required using an extra flag on the pip `--no-cache-dir`.

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir
```

On some versions of Linux you will need to first install pip. Need the Chicken before you can get the Egg (get it... Egg?)

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

If for some reason you are unable to install using pip, don't worry, you can still import `PySimpleGUI` by downloading the file `PySimleGUI.py` and placing it in your folder along with the application that is importing it.

`tkinter` is a requirement for `PySimpleGUI` (the only requirement). Some OS variants, such as Ubuntu, do not some with `tkinter` already installed. If you get an error similar to:

```
ImportError: No module named tkinter then you need to install tkinter. For python 2.7
```

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

For python 3 `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

Comment: (1) What are you complaining about?  The first version of your first answer was one sentence and a link. (2) OK, you copied the information from the page you linked to; that’s good.  But you deleted the link.  That’s bad.  That’s plagiarism.  If you copy something from another site, then you *must* identify the source.  (Block quote formatting is good, too.) (3) When you fixed your first answer (on May 16), you should have ***flagged*** it for undeletion — as you were told by the moderator who deleted it!

Comment: It's not plagiarism if I wrote the information. They're all my words.

Comment: Oh, so you’re the author of the pysimplegui.readthedocs.io web site?  OK, I guess that changes things. But, when you post a link to a web site that you own or control, you should say so (which you didn’t). … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … And I stand by everything else I said.

Comment: Yep, and should be proud of those words too Scott.  Stand tall!  So informative.  So  educational.  Thank you so very much!!!!!  I feel appropriately politely educated.